# Getting boolean result of array

Tags: javascript

let's say I have an array with `n` elements of boolean values.

```
var a = [true,false,true,true,false]
```

How do I do the OR product of the array.

SO that `var result = (true || false || true || true  || false) = true`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `some` :

```
var result = a.some(function(value) {
    return value;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

All these suggestions are far too complex. Just keep it simple. If you want **OR** then you just need to check if the array contains a single `true` value:

```
var result = a.indexOf(true) != -1;
```

---

Similarly, if you wanted **AND** you could just check if it doesn't contain `false` value, also if you want an empty array to result in false then check the length too:

```
var result = a.length > 0 && a.indexOf(false) == -1;
```

---

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/avo9qvvk/2/), that shows both OR and AND in action.

And [here is a performance review](http://jsperf.com/oring-and-array) of all the current answers, where you can see keeping it simple like this is much quicker than the other suggestions (well, Nina is close to mine as her answer is similar, but less readable IMO). Of course you can argue performance isn't going to be noticed with something like this, but still better to use the fastest method anyway.

Comment: Checked it out, but AND doesn't work for empty array.

Comment: @airnet: OK, Ill sort that one out ;) What should be the result for empty array with AND?

Comment: the result for both OR and AND should be false

Answer (score 1):

Short in one command.

```
!!~a.indexOf(true)
```

Comment: `a.indexOf(true) > -1`

Comment: why not just compare with `-1` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may iterate over the array and find it.

```js
var a = [false,false,false,false,false]
var result = a[0];
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    result = result || a[i]
}
alert(result);
```

I hope this would help you

https://jsfiddle.net/0yhhvhu7/3/

Comment: when you find first `true` other loop not needed, because value not changed

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

> The `Array.prototype.reduce()` method applies a function against an accumulator and each value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single value.

```
a.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  return prev || curr;
});
```